# Missing camera adaptors in MATLAB Image Acquisition Toolbox

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use the MATLAB Image Acquisition Toolbox, but I get a warning when I try to recognize cameras with `imaqhwinfo`:

```
>> info=imaqhwinfo
Warning: No Image Acquisition adaptors found. Image acquisition adaptors may
be available as downloadable support packages. Open Support Package
Installer to install additional vendors. 

info = 

    InstalledAdaptors: {}
        MATLABVersion: '8.5 (R2015a)'
          ToolboxName: 'Image Acquisition Toolbox'
       ToolboxVersion: '4.9 (R2015a)'
```

Please advise me on how to set up MATLAB to recognise cameras with the Image Acquisition Toolbox.

Comment: I can't find any adaptors.

Comment: Have you managed to install the adaptors?

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [MATLAB documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/imaq/installing-the-support-packages-for-image-acquisition-toolbox-adaptors.html), all adaptors were pre-installed with the Image Acquisition Toolbox, until MATLAB R2013b. From MATLAB R2014a on, each adaptor has to be installed manually. 
The reason for this is probably that more and more adaptors became available, so not pre-installing *all* adaptors does make sense.
There are detailed instructions in the [MATLAB documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/imaq/installing-the-support-packages-for-image-acquisition-toolbox-adaptors.html):

> To install a support package:
>
> 1. On the MATLAB **Home** tab, in the **Environment** section, click **Add-Ons > Get Hardware Support Packages**.
> 2. In the Add-On Explorer, scroll to the **Hardware Support Packages** section, and click **show all** to find your support package.
> 3. You can refine the list by selecting **Imaging/Cameras** in the **Refine by Hardware Type** section on the left side of the Explorer.
> 4. Select the support package for your adaptor. The table in [Image Acquisition Support Packages for Hardware Adaptors](https://mathworks.com/help/imaq/image-acquisition-support-packages-for-hardware-adaptors.html) shows the names of the support packages for each adaptor type.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this worked for me:

1. Go to **Home** tab
2. **Get Hardware Support Package** under Add-Ons from Environment section
3. choose **Install from Internet** and select **OS Generic Video Interface** from supported drivers
4. Next
5. I accept and Next
6. wait for installation finished. There you go. type 'imaqhwinfo' in Command Window and see 'winvideo' is added.